# Date diff if function in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to SQL. I have two columns in my horse database - date and horse name. The date is the date of when the horse raced and the horse name. I would like a 3rd column to work out the date difference in days between the horses previous run and the this one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Date functions differ in SQL.  One common method is just subtraction.

To get the previous date, you can use the ANSI standard `lag()` function (not available in all databases).

The query would look something like:

```
select h.*,
       (racedate - lag(racedate) over (partition by horse order by racedate) as daysSinceLastRace
from horses h;
```

This will be `NULL` for the first race.

(Note:  Some databases use a "datediff()" function for the difference in days, rather than subtraction.)

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. How would I count the horses runs in a certain preparation? For example - if horse hasn't run in over 90 days it would be 0 then it's next run would be 1 and it's next run 2 and so on until it has a spell again and the count resets. Cheers.

Comment: @Zipping2010 . . . If you have another question, then ask it as a question with sample data and desired results.